# show email sender IMAP-PHP

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I connected my website with my gmail account and I showing all message

the problem is I want to show the email sender I try to use `['header']->senderaddress`

but without any result

my index code

```html
$email = new EmailReader();
  print_r($email->search());

  echo "There are ".$email->Getinboxcount() . 'Messages';

  for($i=0;$i<$email->Getinboxcount();$i++){
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "<h3>Message received from</h3>" . $email->GetMessage($i)['header']->fromaddress;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "<h3>Message received from email : </h3>" . $email->GetMessage($i)['header']->senderaddress;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "<h3>date</h3>" . $email->GetMessage($i)['header']->date;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "<h3>subject/h3>" . $email->GetMessage($i)['header']->subject;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "<h3>text</h3>" . $email->GetMessage($i)['body_text'];
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '*****************************************************************************';

  }
```